# Passing a Named Bean variable as parameter of the Primefaces gmap function in a PF dialog box

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, jsf-2

I wanted to show a Primefaces gmap inside a Primefaces dialog. The latitude/longitude is a Named Bean variable and put as parameter of the Primefaces gmap function as follow :

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:dialog header="MAP" widgetVar="gmapDialog" appendTo="@(body)" modal="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true">

    #{gererAnnoncesMB.coordonneesGPS}
    <p:gmap id="gmap" center=" #{gererAnnoncesMB.coordonneesGPS}" zoom="15" type="terrain" style="width:600px;height:400px" />

</p:dialog>
```

The value of the Bean variable for lat/long is correct, but not pass in the primefaces gmap function where the value of the lat/long variable is set to "00.000000,00.000000" in the generated HTML code :

```
pf.cw(
  "GMap",
  "widget_formVisualisationAnnonce_gmap",
   {
    id:"formVisualisationAnnonce:gmap",
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(00.000000, 00.000000),
    zoom:15,
    fitBounds:false
   }
 );
```

the result is a blank screen with the following Chrome console message :
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on the line of the pf.cw() function.

So 2 questions :

First : Why the Bean variable is not well transmitted to the Primesfaces JS function ?

Second, and less important for me: Why the first 0 of the longitude argument seem to generate this "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".

Many thanks in advance, and apologize, I am a newbie in JSF with very low knowledge in JAVASCRIPT ;-)

Comment: For the missing bean value: When are the values in the bean populated? Try to use `dynamic=true` on the dialog. This will render the dialogs content, the time it is shown, rather than during DOM-Generation.

Comment: First of all, you have a space before the EL. Secondly what does the EL in front of the map show (if you put it as `-#{gererAnnoncesMB.coordonneesGPS}-`  (leading and trailing minus to see 'boundaries' )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and answers.

I didn't knows the dynamic parameter and I will use it now ;-)

For the space before the EL,  it doesn't exist in the real code, just a copy/paste error on my side (but anyway I think this have no impact).

The EL -#{gererAnnoncesMB.coordonneesGPS}- write just before the map show the good GPS lat/long on the screen as wanted. It seem that the second call of the getter (getGererAnnonceMB.coordonneesGPS()) send a "00.000000, 00.000000" value and I don't understand why.

To solve my issue, I just add an JSTL EL value (a variable in the JSF and not in the Managed Bean) and put it in the PF gmap function. And it's working now.
I know it's not a proper solution (quick and dirty one ;-)) ...

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

<p:dialog header="MAP" widgetVar="gmapDialog" appendTo="@(body)" modal="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true" dynamic="true">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">

        <h:outputText value="#{gererAnnoncesMB.coordonneesGPS}" title="coordonnées"/>
        <c:set var="maVariable" value="#{gererAnnoncesMB.coordonneesGPS}" scope="request" />
        <p:gmap id="gmap" center="#{maVariable}" zoom="15" type="terrain" style="width:600px;height:400px" />

    </f:view>

</p:dialog>
```

The getter in the Managed Bean GererAnnonceMB :

```
    public String getCoordonneesGPS() {
    coordonneesGPS = "00.000000, 00.000000";             // Coordonnées GPS de l'Annonce
    if (annonceetendueSelected != null) {
        coordonneesGPS = annonceetendueSelected.getVilLat() + ", " + annonceetendueSelected.getVilLon();
    }
    return coordonneesGPS;
}
```

And in the server log I see that the value of annonceetendueSelected is not NULL.
I will investigate later on and keep you post if I solve this issue.

Many thanks

Regards
Hervé